# Extract object from JSON post data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

From a web page I send JSON file to a nodeJS server. I want at the server side to assign that JSON file to an object and print in the console. Although I read a lot in the internet and tried a lot, I decided to write for help.

Here is what I tried this:

The index.html file:

```html
<form action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="fileinfo">
  <label>File to stash:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Stash the file!" />
</form>
</script>
```

Trough this file I send a valid JSON file.

Here is the server side code:

```
var http = require("http")
var express = require("express")
var url = require("url")
var fs = require("fs")

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.post('/', function(request, response){
  console.log(request.body);      // your JSON
});

app.listen(80);
console.log('Server is listening ... ')
```

And here is the JSON file content:

```
{
    "head":{
        "person":{
            "first name": "Radoslav",
            "second name": "Krasinirov",
            "last-name": "Marinov"
        }
    }
}
```

When I load the file into the html form and hit `Stash the file!`, at the server I get this message in the console:

> { }

Instead I would like to get the file content. How to get the JSON file string only?

Comment: Have you tried `$.getJSON` ?

Comment: your mistake is not reading *documentation* about `<form>` element ... the `enctype` you are supplying is not valid - read all about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype) ... TL;DR there's no such `enctype` for `<form>`s as `application/json`

Comment: I edited the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending content type form on your request, while using `body-parser.json()`, which sets the body field on the request only if content type is `application/json`.

Either change the content type header in youbrequest, or use a suiting body parser

Comment: Could you please show me how to change the content type from the html?

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is with express `body-parser` not able to accept `multipart/form-data` content-type and was first addressed (with full discusion) [here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/88) and then we have a short question & an answer [here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/258) with an answer.

You eventually need [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) and this is how you code will look like.

```
var multer = require('multer')().single();
app.use(multer);
```

Goodluck!